# DATO QUE VIENE DE AJAX Y QUE INSERTO EN UN INPUT ME AGREGA A LA BASE DE DATOS DE MYSQL REPETIDO

Tags: javascript, ajax

Soy todavía muy novado en mucho de los temas y quiero que el formulario tenga un empleado solo selección en la opción selecta su codigo y cargue su nombre en un input o div, hasta aca no tengo problema el problema es que cuando quiero guardarlo en la tablat de mysql me pone el nombre del empleado tanto en el id como en el nombre este es mi código.
Muchas Gracias

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name=color1]").change(function(){

            $('input[name=valor1]').val($(this).val());
        });
});

</script>

<form method="POST" action="NuevaProduccion1.php" class="form-horizontal">

    <select class="form-control"  name="color1" >
                                <option value="">Selecciona Codigo:</option>
                                <?php
                                  $consulta="SELECT * FROM empleados";
                                  $respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
                                  while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta)) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$valores[Nombre].'">'.$valores[C_Empleado].'</option>';
                                  }
                                ?>
                              </select>

                          <input type="" name="valor1" size="40">

                              <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                                    <input type="submit"  value="Guardar" name="Guardar"  class="btn btn-success"></input>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                                </form>

                            <?php

                            if(isset($_POST['Guardar']))

                            {

                                 $codigo_e=$_POST['color1'];
                                 $nombre=$_POST['valor1'];

                                 $conexion->query("INSERT INTO produccion (id,C_Empleado,Nombre) VALUES
                                 ('','$codigo_e','$nombre')");

                                desconectar();
                               echo "Datos Guardados";
                                 ?>
                                <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
                                <meta http-equiv="refresh" 
                                content="1;URL=?"> 
                                <?php

                            }    
                            ?>
                    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Sin mayúscula sostenida, por favor

Comment: Ese fragmento de Javascript hace que cada que seleccionas una opción se copie el valor al segundo campo, por eso es que recibes lo mismo en ambos.